# Voltage biasing problem

Tags: analog, biasing

How can I solve this question?
In the circuit below, the n-channel MOS device operates according to the equation:
i(D)=K(v(GS)−vT)^2,
where K is 9.2 milli-siemens per volt, vT is 0.5 volts. The values of R1, R2, RS and RD are 657, 328.5, 11.6, 11.6 kilo-ohms respectively. Solve the circuit and arrive at the operating point of the MOS device. What is the value of I(D).

[image: Circuit diagram]

Comment: Don't just post your homework for someone else to do. That's lazy. Show your own work, and explain where you are confused. Otherwise your question may be deleted.

Comment: I get about \$I_D\approx 10.127\:\textrm{mA}\$. What do you get, Rohan, and how?

Comment: @jonk - RD and rS are 11.6k - so max possible current is about 250uA with a 5v rail.

Comment: @KevinWhite Understood. But that wasn't clear from the OP's writing (you can easily see that there is no 'k' next to the 11.6 there), so I chose to take the OP literally to see if I could stimulate a response. Got one from you, but not the OP. By the way, I get \$91.9561\:\mu\textrm{A}\$, in that case.

Comment: @jonk - I agree it was unclear

Comment: @KingDuken I did ask the OP. See my first response. Since the OP wants to know *how* to do it, I didn't give that away. In any case, a simple answer is almost worthless -- they only hurt themselves -- and can be useful to others as it can provide a figure they can use to check their own work. I don't see a difficulty.

Comment: To the OP, first solve for \$V_G\$ (easy to do, using \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ and \$V_{CC}\$.) Then write down what you know, regarding the equation for \$I_D\$. I think you should be able to find that you have a quadratic equation that isn't terribly difficult to solve.

Comment: @jonk that's what I tried to do. But I wasn't getting the right answer. See the following two equations: V(GS)+I(D)R(S)=1.66V, I(D)=K(V(GS)-V(T))^2...Are you referring to solving this two equations to find V(GS)? Then I(D) would be V(GS)/R(S), right?

Comment: @jonk sorry if it was unclear and also sorry for the late reply

Comment: @jonk and also 91.9 micro-amp is the correct answer.

Comment: @RohanSawant \$I_D=\frac{V_S}{R_S}=\frac{V_G-V_{GS}}{R_S}\$, right? Does that help?

Comment: @jonk just got the answer. 91.4 micro-amp. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look over your schematic. Other than the supply rails, there are three nodes: \$V_G\$, \$V_D\$, and \$V_S\$. Also, you can construct the fact that \$V_{GS}=V_G-V_S\$. Correct?

You should be able to develop the trivial voltage divider result for the \$\ref{vdiv}\$:

$$V_G=V_{CC}\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}\label{vdiv}\tag{gate voltage}$$

That already solves one of your nodes. The others are similarly trivial. you have the \$\ref{vs}\$ and the \$\ref{vd}\$:

$$V_D=V_{CC}-R_D\cdot I_D\label{vd}\tag{drain voltage}$$

$$V_S=R_S\cdot I_D\label{vs}\tag{source voltage}$$

The \$\ref{vd}\$ isn't terribly important, right now. It will fall out for sanity testing later, once you figure out the value for \$I_D\$.

At this point, all you do is enter into your starting equation:

$$\begin{align*}
I_D&=K\cdot\left(V_{GS}-V_T\right)^2\\\\
&=K\cdot\left(V_G-V_S-V_T\right)^2\\\\
&=K\cdot\left(V_{CC}\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}-R_S\cdot I_D-V_T\right)^2
\end{align*}$$

If you work this correctly, you should wind up with a quadratic equation to solve.

---

EDIT: As you pointed out, a quadratic will often have two possible results. This is where that *sanity testing* I mentioned may come into play.

If you have arranged your equations so that you expect positive results, then it is easy to exclude the negative one, if there is both a negative and positive result. The positive one will be the choice. If there are two positive results, then you apply the currents to both the \$\ref{vd}\$ and \$\ref{vs}\$ computations above. One of the positive values for \$I_D\$ won't make sense, considering your voltage rail, \$V_{CC}\$. So you eliminate that one. (If they are both negative, then you didn't arrange your equations to expect positive results and that is a different problem. Go back and double check your work.)

Comment: When we solve the quadratic equation, we reject one value and take the other. Why do we reject the one?

Comment: @RohanSawant I mentioned the phrase "sanity testing" in the text. One of the values will either be way too large (you can test this by seeing what the voltage drop across \$R_S\$ and \$R_D\$ are and then seeing if this total drop is too large for the power supply rails; or else the value will be negative (and if you have arranged the equations so that they should produce a positive value, you know that must be wrong.) It's just a matter of inspection to know which of the two works.